# Extracting numbers from a string, and ordering a numpy list

Tags: python, arrays, string

I have a string which consists of many numbers inside of it. The string is as follows:

```
['# Wavelength (m) ', 'Observation: 19909', 'Observation: 27028', 'Observation: 16652', 'Observation: 31458', 'Observation: 47548', 'Observation: 21100', 'Observation: 11768', 'Observation: 36969', 'Observation: 36656', 'Observation: 14915', 'Observation: 16766', 'Observation: 18197', 'Observation: 30915', 'Observation: 41090', 'Observation: 48054', 'Observation: 39451', 'Observation: 36999', 'Observation: 23674', 'Observation: 23095', 'Observation: 30768', 'Observation: 31991', 'Observation: 31544', 'Observation: 38008', 'Observation: 16076', 'Observation: 43937', 'Observation: 42251', 'Observation: 36537', 'Observation: 15338', 'Observation: 23522', 'Observation: 47565\n']
```

How do I extract only the numbers from this string? I want to be able to order these numbers by ascending order afterwards.

Also, I have a numpy list as follows:

```
v_list = [] # will store the velocities's in this list
#Between these lines of code there is a function defined which returns some parameters and does a calculation to work out the velocities
velocity_database=v_list.append(v_kms) # store velocity of the galaxy at the end of the growing list of velocities
print("The velocities are",v_list)
```

Giving this console response:

```
The velocities are [23776.307252936745, 29131.102361319136, 31615.49519071778, 17021.094456442446, 18172.375147257782, 31445.40515744717, 12649.6243034793, 14562.29510500802, 15974.290956463285, 16857.779678784023, 17837.097387347385, 20559.403621751506, 25351.46462858142, 20243.658821061777, 31645.67231184538, 23414.882588799854, 24994.813874811956, 32256.096602708625, 35258.16983158886, 26024.330289709895, 23181.488351828662, 17062.733161445263, 32680.9979695023, 21874.728746293586, 13398.338349854597, 19380.382584101142, 18428.479732444466, 19193.317697089064, 5364.615429193248, 11306.957725232642]
```

How can I print a new list that has these velocities in ascending order?

Comment: This is a Python list and string task.  `numpy` does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Simple list comprehension. Cast to `int` or `float` according to your requirements.

```py
>>> obs = ['# Wavelength (m) ', 'Observation: 19909', 'Observation: 27028', 'Observation: 16652', 'Observation: 31458', 'Observation: 47548', 'Observation: 21100', 'Observation: 11768', 'Observation: 36969', 'Observation: 36656', 'Observation: 14915', 'Observation: 16766', 'Observation: 18197', 'Observation: 30915', 'Observation: 41090', 'Observation: 48054', 'Observation: 39451', 'Observation: 36999', 'Observation: 23674', 'Observation: 23095', 'Observation: 30768', 'Observation: 31991', 'Observation: 31544', 'Observation: 38008', 'Observation: 16076', 'Observation: 43937', 'Observation: 42251', 'Observation: 36537', 'Observation: 15338', 'Observation: 23522', 'Observation: 47565\n']
>>> obs = obs[1:]
>>> obs
['Observation: 19909', 'Observation: 27028', 'Observation: 16652', 'Observation: 31458', 'Observation: 47548', 'Observation: 21100', 'Observation: 11768', 'Observation: 36969', 'Observation: 36656', 'Observation: 14915', 'Observation: 16766', 'Observation: 18197', 'Observation: 30915', 'Observation: 41090', 'Observation: 48054', 'Observation: 39451', 'Observation: 36999', 'Observation: 23674', 'Observation: 23095', 'Observation: 30768', 'Observation: 31991', 'Observation: 31544', 'Observation: 38008', 'Observation: 16076', 'Observation: 43937', 'Observation: 42251', 'Observation: 36537', 'Observation: 15338', 'Observation: 23522', 'Observation: 47565\n']
>>> obs_nums = [int(item.split(' ')[1]) for item in obs]
>>> obs_nums
[19909, 27028, 16652, 31458, 47548, 21100, 11768, 36969, 36656, 14915, 16766, 18197, 30915, 41090, 48054, 39451, 36999, 23674, 23095, 30768, 31991, 31544, 38008, 16076, 43937, 42251, 36537, 15338, 23522, 47565]
```

Also for printing in ascending order, you can simply sort the list by `sort` method.

```
>>> obs_nums.sort()
>>> obs_nums
[11768, 14915, 15338, 16076, 16652, 16766, 18197, 19909, 21100, 23095, 23522, 23674, 27028, 30768, 30915, 31458, 31544, 31991, 36537, 36656, 36969, 36999, 38008, 39451, 41090, 42251, 43937, 47548, 47565, 48054]
```